# Write/delete text by character

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

I try to make change of any text by char by char (show text by char, delete text by char and show another one char by char).

**What I actually have?**

```
var i = 0;
var terms = ['text  <b>bold</b>', 'longer text <b>bold</b>', '<b>bold</b> text 3'];

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var el = $('#el');
    var wr = $('#wr');

    setInterval(function() {
        var str = el.html(); // doesn't work (still shows all content, not sliced one)
        el.html(str.substring(0, str.length - 1));
    }, 300 / str.length); // (300 / str.length) - do all animation in 300s

    i++;

    if (i === 3) {
        i = 0;
    }

}, 2500);
```

I have problem with slicing last char, so I don't get to adding new text so far :-(

**One of variants I tried:**

```
...
var text = terms[i].split('');

setInterval(function() {
        el.html(text); // add sliced text in loop... not working as expected            
        // ...    
        text = text.slice(0, -1); // slice text by last character
    }, 300 / text.length);
```

**Okay, due to the comments a little bit explanation**

I have an element

`<span id=el>text <b>bold</b></span>`

In 300ms interval I need to remove this text char by char.

```
<span id=el>text <b>bold</b></span>
<span id=el>text <b>bol</b></span>
<span id=el>text <b>bo</b></span>
<span id=el>text <b>b</b></span>
<span id=el>text <b></b></span> // remove 'b'
<span id=el>text</span> // remove ' ' and empty bold
<span id=el>tex</span>
<span id=el>te</span>
<span id=el>t</span>
<span id=el></span>
// now element is empty, since start it's 300ms

// and now I need to put there new text, char by char (whole phrase 300ms again)
<span id=el>l</span>
<span id=el>lo</span>
<span id=el>lon</span>
...
<span id=el>longer tex</span>
<span id=el>longer text</span>
<span id=el>longer text </span> // add space
<span id=el>longer text <b>b</b></span> // add 'b' into bold
<span id=el>longer text <b>bo</b></span>
<span id=el>longer text <b>bol</b></span>
<span id=el>longer text <b>bold</b></span>
// after 2500ms remove this char by char again and replace by third. Etc.
```

Etc. Can tou help me with that please? Tried that for last 2 days, many attempts, no result... 
Thanks

Comment: Where do  `terms` come into play? And what are the definitions of the various values in `classes`? It would be helpful if you added some more code and turned this into a complete code snippet.

Comment: please explain what you have, what you want. Make your question more clear

Comment: @Booboo: `var terms` is defined at the 2nd line.

Comment: Yes, but we do not know the definition of class `cls1`, do we? I said the "values *in* `classes`". Presumably this is  a `CSS` style.

Comment: I've added a little explanation... more clear? :-)

Comment: @Booboo: I need to change classname too, but it's not a question here (it's done). I need to change `#el` content, char by char in a loop. Deleted irrelevant `classes` from question.

Comment: @DupinderSingh: better with additional explanation?

Comment: @Booboo: 300ms is the total time for text change, when text has 10 characters, each cahracter time change is 30ms. If the text is longer and has 30 chars, each char change has to be 10ms... if it's bad in JS, how to write it better? Really dont know how better explain that.

Comment: @Booboo: when text.length === 0, there should be clearInterval, probably... but the problem is that the text in span is still in full length, last char isn't removed... Thats the main point I need to solve...

Comment: `terms` is not referenced anywhere in your loop. if `el` is initialized to one of the elements of `terms`, where do the other elements come into play? Also, if you are reducing the string by one character every 300ms, don't you end up at some point with `text <b>bold</` and not `text <b>bol</b>`?

Comment: And after 2500ms, I see no logic that increases the length of the string by one each time through the loop. That is, there is nothing like: `el.html(str.substring(0, str.length + 1));`

Comment: @Booboo: I'm not a JS developer, if you know how to do it correctly, please post it as answer. I passed a lot of time with that and these comments tells me 'sorry, you have everything bad', what I know. But you don't tell me how is it correctly. Or maybe yes, but I don't see it there. For your answer I will be really happy! :-)

Comment: @Booboo: and yes, there is no logic how to increment the new text, because I still don't have a decrementation solved. Incrementation will be almost the same in reversed order, its thing I could solve than myself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would organize my code to shrink and grow an element. The only sensible way I can do this is to first replace `<` and `>` by the corresponding entity codes `&lt;` and `&gt;` so that these characters are not interpreted as actual tags. These 4-letter entity codes will be removed and added as a single unit. In this way you can shrink the string one quasi-character at a time from right to left and still have valid HTML at all times.

The `Promise` api (well, acually jQuery's $.Deferred version of this) is used to be able to know in a deterministic fashion when the shrink-grow cycle, which is an asynchronous process, has completed to then start the 2500 ms delay (which is another asynchronous process) before beginning anew.

```js
$(function() {

    function shrink_grow(resolve, term)
    {
        term = term.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

        let el = $('#el');
        el.html(term);

        let interval = setInterval(shrinker, 30);

        function shrinker()
        {
            let str = el.html();
            let n = str.length >= 4 && (str.endsWith('&gt;') || str.endsWith(`&lt;`)) ? 4 : 1;
            el.html(str.substr(0, str.length - n));
            if (str.length === 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                interval = setInterval(grower, 30);
            }
        }


        function grower()
        {
            let str = el.html();
            if (str.length == term.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                resolve(undefined); // we are done
            }
            else if (str.length <= term.length - 4 && (term.substr(str.length + 1, 4) == '&lt;' || term.substr(str.length + 1, 4) == '&gt;')) {
                el.html(term.substr(0, str.length + 4));
            }
            else {
                el.html(term.substr(0, str.length + 1));
            }
        }

    }

    function pause(milliseconds)
    {
        // Create a new Deferred object
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        // Resolve the Deferred after the amount of time specified by milliseconds
        setTimeout(deferred.resolve, milliseconds);

        return deferred.promise();
    }


    let terms = ['text <b>bold</b>', 'longer text <i>italic</i> text', '<b>bold</b> text 3'];
    let term_number = 0;
    let deferred = $.Deferred();
    let promise = deferred.promise();
    shrink_grow(deferred.resolve, terms[term_number++]);
    promise.then(function() {
        pause(2500).then(function() {
            let deferred = $.Deferred();
            let promise = deferred.promise();
            shrink_grow(deferred.resolve, terms[term_number++]);
            promise.then(function() {
                pause(2500).then(function() {
                    let deferred = $.Deferred();
                    let promise = deferred.promise();
                    shrink_grow(deferred.resolve, terms[term_number++]);
                    promise.then(function() {
                        console.log('done');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="el"></span>
```

**And Keeping the tags intact**

This is very complicated, however:

```js
$(function() {

    let TOTAL_TIME = 300;

    function shrink_grow(resolve, term)
    {
        let el = $('#el');

        let matches = term.match(/<([^>])+>(.*?)<\/\1>/); // look for internal tag
        let internalTagTextLength = matches ? matches[2].length : 0;
        let internalTagText = internalTagTextLength ? matches[2] : '';
        let strlen = term.length;
        if (matches) {
            strlen -= matches[1].length * 2 + 5;
        }
        let shrinkGrowInterval = TOTAL_TIME / strlen;
        if (shrinkGrowInterval < 16) {
            shrinkGrowInterval = 16;
        }

        let interval = setInterval(grower, shrinkGrowInterval);

        function shrinker()
        {
            let str = el.html();
            let matches = str.match(/<([^>])+>(.*?)<\/\1>$/); // <i>text</i> at end of string, for example
            if (matches) {
                let str2 = matches[2];
                if (str2.length < 2) { // get rid of entire tag
                    str2 = matches[0];
                    let n = str2.length;
                    let l = str.length - n;
                    el.html(str.substr(0, l));
                    if (l === 0) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        resolve(undefined); // we are done
                    }
                }
                else {
                    let str2a = str2.substr(0, str2.length - 1);
                    str = str.replace(/<([^>])+>(.*?)<\/\1>$/, '<' + matches[1] + '>' + str2a + '</' + matches[1] + '>');
                    el.html(str);
                }
            }
            else {
                el.html(str.substr(0, str.length - 1));
                if (str.length === 0) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    resolve(undefined); // we are done
                }
            }
        }


        function grower()
        {
            let str = el.html();
            if (str.length == term.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                interval = setInterval(shrinker, shrinkGrowInterval);
            }
            else {
                let matches = term.substr(str.length).match(/^<([^>])+>(.*?)<\/\1>/);  // start of <i>text</i>, for example?
                if (matches) {
                    let str2 = '<' + matches[1] + '>' + matches[2].substr(0, 1) + '</' + matches[1] + '>';
                    el.html(str + str2);
                }
                else {
                    let matches = str.match(/<([^>])+>(.*?)<\/\1>$/); // <i>text</i> at end of string, for example
                    if (matches) {
                        let str2 = matches[2];
                        let l = str2.length;
                        if (l == internalTagTextLength) {
                            el.html(term.substr(0, str.length + 1));
                        }
                        else {
                            let str2a = internalTagText.substr(0, l + 1);
                            str = str.replace(/<([^>])+>(.*?)<\/\1>$/, '<' + matches[1] + '>' + str2a + '</' + matches[1] + '>');
                            el.html(str);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        el.html(term.substr(0, str.length + 1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


    let terms = ['text <b>bold</b>', 'longer text <i>italic</i> text', '<b>bold</b> text 3'];
    let nTerms = terms.length;
    let termNumber = -1;

    function callShrinkGrow()
    {
        if (++termNumber >= nTerms) {
            termNumber = 0;
        }
        let deferred = $.Deferred();
        let promise = deferred.promise();
        shrink_grow(deferred.resolve, terms[termNumber]);
        promise.then(callShrinkGrow);
    }

    callShrinkGrow();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<span id="el"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look on it. What I see, you have 300ms for each letter change, I need to have 300ms for hide/show whole text. And than you commented problem with `<b>` tags, but you do nothing with them... Do you have any idea, how to improve that? Of course, +1 for this at least.

Comment: I changed the interval to 30 ms. and the `<span>` to include a `<b>` tag and therefore the jQuery selctor.

Comment: once again :-) The interval shouldn't be static 30ms, but dynamic (it's okay, do myself)... But the text which are shown/hidden isn't just inside `<b>`, it's text **including** `<b>`. See the question, string to shown/hide is for example `text  <b>bold</b>` (9 characters including space).

Comment: I changed whole element content (not just children `b`), so selector is `$('#el')`. The content is eg. `text <b>bold</b>` (9 chars, each char time change 300ms / 9 ~ 33ms), or `longer text with <i>italic</i> text.` (29 chars, each char time change 300/29ms ~ 10ms).

Comment: You need two selectors `$(#el b)` and `(#el)` assigned to `el2`. When you are shrinking the first one and the text length is 0, get the contents of the second selector, `el2.html()` and save in `text2` and continue `shrinking` with `el2.html()` until its length goes to 0 and then you switch to `growing`. In `growing` you start with `el2.html()` util the length is `test2.length` and then you switch to `el.html()` until the length is `text.length`. The only tricky bit is on each call to `shrinking` and `growing` which element you are using. But you can figure it out, I am sure.

Comment: Eh? Sorry, from your comment I'm so... confused... there can be `<b>` inside, but can be `<i>` inside too. This nested element can be at the beginning of content, at the end, or in the middle (but always will be max. 1, I don't know which and where). Can you update your answer please? If not, I'll try it myself, it take me more time than you. Maybe I can offer you any reward (via bank account)? Real data can be `var terms = ['text  <b>bold</b>', 'longer text <i>italic</i> text', '<b>bold</b> text 3'];`.

Comment: What is the *precise* specification of the *entire* problem. If this is a homework assignment (this doesn't seem like a real-world problem), then edit the question and include word-for-word the text of the assignment. If this is something else, you need to describe more precisely what the problem is. For example: "There is a `<span>` tag with one embedded tag that can be either a `<b>` or a `<i>`. The contents of the `<span>` tag is to shrink and grow by one character every 30 ms ... etc. " The precision is required because I had asked you about variable `terms` and you never really answered.

Comment: No, isn't homework :-)  We have actually 4 services, which have to be changed in one element on homepage char by char (`'<b>wedding</b> photos', 'videos of <b>something</b>', etc.`). All what I need is in QUESTION (last section with explanation), we need to change whole element content (`$('#el')` is right) and the content is pure text, or pure text + one nested inline element (B, I, maybe A is possible) - see question and `var terms` (exactly type of data we have). And we need to spell this content (show/hide). **Example is in the Question at the end**.

Comment: Well, I've updated my answer (see the first code snippet).

Comment: Booboo, The second snippet looks good, just two small updates. 1. invisible text change (start with first term (can be directly in HTML), delete this term char by char, when the length is 0, change to next one and show the second one. After showing 2nd, remove 2nd char by char, then show 3rd, etc.) - now there is visible skip of text. 2. Infinite loop (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 1st, 2nd, etc.). Then you can send me a paypal, I'll pay you something for that, really helped me :-)

Comment: Update 1 means, that you change #el content, when its content is visible, I need to change it when it's hidden. Your schema is: 'hide, show, change. Hide, show, change'. I need: '[first is visible in HTML by default], hide, change, show, hide, change'.

Comment: I am away on vacation with nothing but a smartphone for several more days and can’t look at this until I return. I am mot interested in program-for-hire work. If this is a trivial change I will make it else you should look for somebody else to do this.

Comment: I don't know if its trivial but I think if you are able to write what you wrote above (many thanks), it could be quite simply for you. That's the last change/update I need in this code (I'm not a programmer). And because I know it takes you any time, I'm able to pay you (not for this last change, I mean for whole time you gave me here). I really don't to hire you, just tried to appreciate your time here :-) It's up to you (if you help me once more again, and if you let me to pay you for all you did for me) :-)

Comment: I made a change. It now seems from your latest description that when the next content us out up, it is shown full length and then is decreased character by character. That is, it is never grown character by character because you said "show and then remove character by character" but you did not say "show character by character". But if you meant show character by character first, it's a minor change.

Comment: Hi Booboo, thanks for this change, I not so strong in English (it's not my 1st language), so sorry :-) Increase and decrease char by char, everytime please. Then it will be great!

Comment: I've made the change.

Comment: Booboo, you're great! Really thanks for your answer, comments and patience!

Answer (score 0):

Okay according to my understanding, you want to show string/text char by char. So I think this will help you.

```js
var str = "Hello World";
var c = "";


var i = 0;
(function loop(){
    if (i++ > str.length-1) return;
    c = c + str[i-1];
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("#charP").text(c);
    loop();
   }, 100);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p id="charP"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: No, first remove text char by char, than show another one. Show/hide in 300ms independently on text length. And part of text is in bold as I wrote in question.